# Need to remove the Notifications from the notifications list in the Salesfoce Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Need to remove the Notifications from the notifications list in the Salesfoce Lightning once users Acknowledge it.

Comment: if you are using process builder you can send custom notification which has this functionality

Comment: Actually I was looking for, the Notification for the Task and Event for the particular Case, which located at top right of the Salesforce lightning page. Even we are marked as complete or Delete the event or task related to case still we are seeing the notification under the notification list. Am just wondering if we can have the solution for clear the notification.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who stumbles across this in 2024...

There still doesn't seem to be a way to clear the notifications list (https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgnlUAB/clear-items-on-the-lightning-bell-notification) and the default behaviour is to show the last 50 notifications that are less than 30 days old (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notif_builder_considerations.htm&type=5).  Older notifications will eventually disappear and new notifications can push old notifications off the "bottom" of the list.